# Android intent.resolveActivity returns null in API 30

Tags: android, android-activity, android-11, resolveactivity, android-api-30

In our app we have payment gateway implementation. We are opening intent to open GPay, PhonePay, Paytm and other apps. Please find the below code snipped,

```
String url = "upi://pay?pa=fcbizpayg@freecharge&pn=PAYG&mc=7299&tid=AXIFRCO1506202118501b5bu4s903cafgu4&tr=AXIFRCO1506202118501b5bu4s903cafgu4&am=50.00&cu=INR";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(url);

Intent appChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay using");

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivityForResult(appChooser, PAYMENT_REQUEST);
} else {
     Toast.makeText(PaymeroUserDetailsActivity.this, "No UPI app found! Please Install to Proceed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I added "queries" tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
        <data android:scheme="upi" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Even though UPI apps are installed on device but we are getting No UPI app found! Please Install to Proceed!

Please assist me what I do.

Comment: You should mention packages in queries. Package visibility

Comment: @blackapps can u please explain it in detail.

Comment: The simplest answer has always been to just wrap the `startActivityForResult()` call in a `try`/`catch` block and handle the exception. Not only does that handle missing activities but is also handles any other problems that might crop up. Beyond that, I think that your `resolveActivity()` and `<queries>` should be for set up for the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, not the chooser `Intent`. Or, if you *really* want to use `resolveActivity()` for the chooser itself, remove the `<data>` element, as the chooser `Intent` has no scheme.

Comment: @Amit yadav solution

Comment: @JithishPN Sorry, I don't have any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 11 - There is a new restriction on package visibility using package manager. getPackageManager().resolveActivity().

**due to this return as  null**

Solution :

Queries has to be added into your manifest.

Example:

```
<queries>
    <!--for WebView -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
```

Refer : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases